# iOS: transparent text to show the background thru text

Tags: ios, text, transparent

I am trying to make the background visible thru text. Here's an example.

[image: background color showing thru text]

I made it work using the following code.

```
- (UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(CGImageRef)maskRef {
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);

    // returns new image with mask applied
    return maskedImage;
}

- (void)setImageForView:(UIImageView *)imageView withText:(NSString *)text {
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:45], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor] };
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

    CGPoint center = imageView.center;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width + 10, 41);
    imageView.center = center;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw a dark gray background
    CGRect rect = imageView.bounds;
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    // Draw the text upside-down
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality( context , kCGInterpolationHigh );
    [text drawInRect:CGRectMake((rect.size.width - size.width) / 2, (rect.size.height - size.height) / 2, size.width, size.height) withAttributes:attributes];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // Create an image mask from what we've drawn so far
    CGImageRef alphaMask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    imageView.image = [self maskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white"] withMask:alphaMask];
}
```

It almost works, but because it's using the rendered text as a mask, it seems to lose antialiasing effect as in this example.

[image: aliased edges]

I wonder if there's a way to get the result like the first image. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an alpha value while setting your text colour? Both UIColor and CGColor allow the use of an alpha value to set a transparency for the text.

For example, you could use something like

```
yourTextColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor; //remove the ".CGColor" if you are using UIColor
```

This creates a semi-transparent greyish color. UIColor also has a method to set RGBA values, in case you wanted specific colours.

Looking at your images, I would suggest an alpha value in the range of 0.85-0.95.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Looking further at your code, there might be a possibility that you are not providing for a retina display screen when you are beginning the imageContext. I would suggest replacing this statement:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
```

with this block:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))//retina-display
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
else //non-retina display
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size);
```

Comment: Thanks, but changing the alpha value of the text doesn't give the same effect that I need. I want the background to clearly show thru the text. I think I have the solution totally different from this approach. I'll update with the solution I found soon.